How to use IAM Role for OpenSearch connector (opensearch-2) with AWS Managed OpenSearch
OpenSearch allows authentication with IAM role (Backend role).
I am using Flink to move data into OpenSearch. How can I use Flink with OpenSearch-2 connector to use Flink's role for authentication instead of the username & password?

I looked online and unfortunately flink-opensearch-connector doesn't support IAM auth role integration. As per official documentation of opensearch connector it only supports username and password authentication as of now.
Flink Open Search connector
